# Изменять переменную при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: android, android-studio, android-button

Всем добрый день или вечер, возможно кто-нибудь знает как решить мою проблему. Я пишу программу на андроид и мне необходимо что бы при нажатии на кнопку у меня от предварительно заданной переменной отнималось определенное число, что то типа декремента мне кажется, то есть по факту должна быть заданная переменная целочисленная и только при нажатии на кнопку нужно отнимать заданное значение и перезаписывать обновленную переменную. Пробовал циклом for, while и просто if но эти все варианты не дали нужного результата. Буду благодарен за любую помощь или совет.

Comment: На кнопку нужно повесить `onClickListener`. 

В методе нажатия сможете изменять значение переменной хоть циклом, хоть декрементом. И в нём же сможете вставить обновлённое значение переменной в какой-либо графический элемент

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну как по мне, то для этого нужно использовать `SharedPreferences`, чтобы сохранять новое значение:

К примеру возьмём переменную `int`, которая равна `1000`;

```
private SharedPreferences mPreferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;

private int simpleValue = 1000;
private int newValue;
```

Добавим в методе `onCreate` две кнопки;

```
mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
mEditor = mPreferences.edit();

findViewById(R.id.btn_value).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            simpleValue--;
            mEditor.putInt("value", simpleValue).apply();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Value = " + simpleValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    newValue = mPreferences.getInt("value", 1000);
```

Как видите в первой кнопке мы меняем значение переменной и сохраняем его, а во второй кнопке получаем уже измененную переменную, которая уже будет равна 500.

Comment: спасибо за совет, а на одну кнопку это сделать можно как-то?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko если вы объясните что конкретно вы хотите сделать, возможно вам предложат способ решения по лучше. Да, вы можете в одну кнопку сделать.

Comment: Если ответ вас устраивает и в нем есть решение, нажмите на галочку слева от ответа.

Comment: мне нужно что бы я мог в любой момент нажать на кнопку и ранее инициализированная переменная уменьшалась на определенную величину

Comment: ` up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                int j=200;
                if (up.isClickable())
                {
                    j=j-10; textInfo.setText(stInfo);
                }
                else
                {
                    textInfo.setText(stInfo);
                }

            }
        });`

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko изменил код, при каждом нажатии на кнопку переменная `SimpleValue` будет уменьшаться на `1`, а потом где вам надо получить остаток присваиваете переменной `newValue` переменную в `Preferences` и передаете её как новое значение.

Comment: Благодарен за помощь